# jQuery drag perfect, but does not drop on ASP MVC4 partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, drag-and-drop

I have partial view in MVC4 project. On this view I have DevExpress html-editor, list of items, which I want drop into editor and div, which hides editor when dragging start(drag&drop directly in editor is to slow).

Here is a code

http://jsfiddle.net/ghusse/zrbCj/

JS initializing of draggable and droppable:

```
    this.initializeDragNDrop = function(){
    
        console.log('D&D initializing.');

        $("#Shield ").droppable({
            drop: function (event, ui) { _this.OnActionItemDrop(); }
        });

        $("#ActionItemList div").draggable({
            start: function () { _this.OnActionItemDragStart(this); },
            stop: function () { _this.OnActionItemDragStop(this); },
            revert: true
        });

        console.log('D&D initialized.');
    

    };
```

Chrome console output:

> D&D initializing.
> D&D initialized.
> drag started.
> drag stopped.

Item drags and reverts correctly. But drop does not occur.
P.S. Mouseover event for #Shield occurs correctly.

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle reproducing your problem to be helped.

Comment: i think its revert: 'valid' not revert: true

Answer (score 0):

i think its `revert: 'valid'` not `revert: true`